# MATE: Alt key focusing application's menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, alt, mate, gnome2

One of things I like in Windows is that in almost every app I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and app's main menu becomes focused. Unfortunately this doesn't work in MATE. (I use Linux Mint 13, if that matters).

I know that I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><letter></kbd> (say, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open "File" menu in most apps), but, first of all, not all of apps have English menus (I'm Russian, and some apps have a Russian UI), and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><non_english_letter></kbd> doesn't work. And second, I have some global shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><letter></kbd>, and these shortcuts of course override the application menu selection.

Simple <kbd>Alt</kbd> focusing first menu item is just great.

How can I achieve the same behavior here?

Comment: Note that this was inherited from Gnome 2. Pressing `alt` also does not activate the window menu on Gnome 2.32.1 so the problem is not MATE specific.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal:

Select Edit from Menu bar --> Keyboard Shortcuts

Uncheck "Enable menu access keys (such as Alt+F to open the File menu)"

This will give back the general terminal shortcuts we use with Alt key.